# Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’ haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I'm trying to do an exercise that gives a list of every path of a binary tree from leaf to root

here's my code:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node (Tree) Int (Tree)

go (Leaf a) = (a : []) : []
go (Node l n r) = insev((go l):(go r)) n

insev :: [[a]] -> a -> [[a]]
insev [[]] x = []
insev (h:t) x = (insb h x) : (insev t x)

insb [] num = num : []
insb (h:t) num = h:(insb t num)
```

it should be correct from logical perspective but i am new to haskell and i don't know why i get this error

```
Main.hs:21:19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected: [[Int]]
        Actual: [[[Int]]]
    • In the expression: insev ((go l) : (go r)) n
      In an equation for ‘go’:
          go (Node l n r) = insev ((go l) : (go r)) n
   |
21 | go (Node l n r) = insev ((go l):(go r)) n
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Main.hs:21:34: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Int]’
      Expected: [[[Int]]]
        Actual: [[Int]]
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(go r)’
      In the first argument of ‘insev’, namely ‘((go l) : (go r))’
      In the expression: insev ((go l) : (go r)) n
   |
21 | go (Node l n r) = insev ((go l):(go r)) n
   |                                  ^^^^

Main.hs:21:41: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘insev’, namely ‘n’
      In the expression: insev ((go l) : (go r)) n
      In an equation for ‘go’:
          go (Node l n r) = insev ((go l) : (go r)) n
   |
21 | go (Node l n r) = insev ((go l):(go r)) n
```

Comment: `::` is used to declare types did you mean to use `++`?

Comment: Provide explicit function types, as it generally helps improve error messages if you assert the type you want, rather than letting GHC infer the type from incorrect code. `go :: Tree -> [[Int]]`.

Comment: @chepner same error

Comment: @cafce25 yes typo i wanted to use :

Comment: @LeonardoRosati No, you wanted `++`. You can't cons an `[[Int]]` onto an `[[Int]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without even looking at the rest of the code, this is never<sup>*</sup> going to fly:

```
(go l) : (go r)
```

Presumably `go` is returning something of the same type in both calls, but the arguments to `(:)` *must* have different types:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Perhaps you want `(++)` instead, whose arguments must have the same types:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

<sup>*</sup> Okay, yes, it is possible to write `go` in a way that invalidates the next sentence's assumption that it is returning the same type in both calls. But that's a pretty unusual situation to be in, and one you have to pretty consciously try to arrive at.

Comment: that was the whole code, btw thanks now it is compiling

Comment: @LeonardoRosati When I said "the rest of the code", I meant "all of the code that is not `(go l) : (go r)`". I was not trying to imply you'd hidden any from us in the question, so apologies if that is what you heard.